# If you lift something does the internal energy increase or remain unchanged?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy

So change in internal energy $\Delta U=Q+W$; so in lifting an object you do work on it, thus increasing its internal energy. Is this correct?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I'd say that the internal energy remains unchanged and that there is no work done on the system.

Comment: The added energy of lifting an object is not internal to the object, it is "between" or "among" the Earth and the object. Specifically, for a closed system the exact location of that system's energy can be thought of as at the system's center of mass. The internal energy of the object remains unchanged.

Comment: FYI "*Internal energy is the total energy of a closed system of molecules, or the sum of the molecular kinetic energy and potential energy in a substance. The macroscopic kinetic and potential energies don’t matter for internal energy – if you move the whole closed system or change its gravitational potential energy, the internal energy remains the same.*" This contradicts the most voted answer at this time. I don't know if this statement is correct though. [Source](https://sciencing.com/internal-energy-physics-definition-formula-how-to-calculate-13722770.html)

Answer (score 6):

Not a silly question! Although your formula is the way that we often memorize the First Law, the *true* First Law is actually
$$
 \Delta (U + KE + PE) = Q + W_\text{non-grav}
$$
where $KE$ and $PE$ are, respectively, the kinetic and potential energy and $W_\text{non-grav}$ is the work done by all forces *except* gravity. When elevating an object, work is done on the object, but its potential energy changes by the same amount (i.e., $\Delta U$ is indeed $0$). The First Law then breaks down to
$$
 \Delta PE = W_\text{non-grav}
$$
...which we know to be true from physics. The reason that the simplified form of the first law is so commonly referenced is that we often encounter systems in which $\Delta PE = \Delta KE = 0$

**Edit:** there is actually more than one way to look at this

1. View Gravity as a force. In this view, the first law is still written as
   $$
      \Delta (U +KE) = Q + W_\text{incl. grav}
   $$
   but $W_\text{incl. grav}$ includes both the work done by the external force which elevates the object *and* by the force of gravity. These effects cancel out to zero.
2. View gravity as a potential - i.e., track its effect by using potential energy rather than by considering it as a force which does work. In this view, the first law is as I wrote it above (first equation) and $W_\text{non-grav}$ the work done by all forces *except* gravity.

The two perspectives are equivalent because gravitational potential energy is defined by $\Delta PE_\text{grav} = - W_\text{grav}$.

Comment: "*the true First Law is actually Δ(U+KE+PE) = ...*". For my understanding could you clarify what is U (U != PE+KE as I expected)? Also why do you include potential energy from gravity into PE? I assumed KE and PE were the kinetic and potential energies found at microscopic level only, e.g. for PE it would include the energy in chemical and nuclear bounds, and from internal electric and magnetic moments, and for KE it would be the microscopic motion of particles, atoms and molecules.

Comment: This is the form of the first law we'd use in classical thermodynamics, where we are only thinking about the macro scale, so microscopic kinetic and potential energy (like the chemical and nuclear bonds you mentioned) is all lumped together as the internal energy U. KE and PE are the *macroscopic* kinetic and potential energies.

Comment: So all microscopic energies are in the internal energy U. As the question is about U, not KE or PE, the answer is changing height doesn't impact the internal energy U?

Comment: That's right. Changes in gravitational potential energy due to elevating the entire system would change the macroscopic potential energy PE, but not the internal energy U.

Answer (score 5):

**Why is  work done by a force when a body is lifted?**

To counteract the gravitational force which would work had there not been the force & thus failing to move the object upward.

**Does it increase the internal energy of the body?**

Gravitational potential energy is a property of two objects; ***not of a single one***. You can't distribute the potential energy as part of it as this object's & the remaining part to the other object. Potential energy is of the ***system*** and not of a single body constituting the system.

So, when you lift the body, you are increasing the potential energy of the system (earth-object) & not *increase the internal energy of the object.*